# Select dropdown boxes not working on Android Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, bigcommerce

**UPDATED 5/20 with resolution!**

After much research, I found out the issue had to do with the [fastclick JS plugin](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) not working well with older versions of android. I added the class "needsclick" to the the select box and VOILA! -- I am able to select the box now in older Android version (4.2).

It appears the fastclick was causing a double "touchstart" event, so the select box was opening and then closing again because of a double click.

**Original Post**

I am having trouble getting a select box to work on Android device. It works on all other devices, but on certain android devices, I'm unable to select the box. It looks as if it's getting highlighted, but the options never open.

Here are examples of the select box that are not working in android:
[examples removed]

I have tried to play around with the positioning but am still getting this error. The site is hosted on Bigcommerce, but I don't think that is the issue. Wondering if anyone has had this issue before or might know a workaround?